# freeze_graph MemoryError for .pbtxt from TF.Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to freeze the graph for checkpoints that have been output by Multi-GPU TF Estimator. Here is the command I used.

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph --input_graph models/graph.pbtxt --input_checkpoint models/model.ckpt-40886 --output_graph hello.pb --output_node_names Decoder/Layer8/filter --input_binary=false
```

It errors out with the following MemoryError. The graph.pbtxt file is about 1.5GBs and my machine has 64Gigs of RAM.

```
  .....
  .....
  .....
  File "/home/will/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 837, in _MergeMessageField
self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "/home/will/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 749, in _MergeField
tokenizer.Consume(':')
  File "/home/will/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1100, in Consume
if not self.TryConsume(token):
  File "/home/will/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1087, in TryConsume
self.NextToken()
  File "/home/will/pyenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1336, in NextToken
match = self._TOKEN.match(self._current_line, self._column)
  MemoryError
```

Is there any way to get model freezing to work on training checkpoint outputs from TF Estimator?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Python? If it's 64-bit try to debug using Heapy to see if you actually go out of memory or it's some other issue.

Comment: I am using 64bit python. I am watching my RAM usage using "watch free -m". The freeze scripts errors out when the usage it max.